# javascript - redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010

I can get the code to pop-up both alert but redirecting is not working. After adding an item it should redirect.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
fields = init_fields();
// Where to go when cancel is clicked
goToWhenCanceled = '/test/English/YouCanceled.aspx';

// Edit the redirect on the cancel-button's
$('.ms-ButtonHeightWidth[id$="GoBack"]').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
            STSNavigate(goToWhenCanceled);
      })
});

// Edit the form-action attribute to add the source=yourCustomRedirectPage
function setOnSubmitRedir(redirURL){
var action = $("#aspnetForm").attr('action');
var end = action.indexOf('&');
    if(action.indexOf('&')<0){
        newAction = action + "?Source=" + redirURL;
    }else{
        newAction = action.substring(0,end) + "&Source=" + redirURL;
    }
$("#aspnetForm").attr('action',newAction);
alert(redirURL);
}

/*
// Use this for adding a "static" redirect when the user submits the form
$(document).ready(function(){
    var goToWhenSubmitted = '/test/English/ThankYou.aspx';
    setOnSubmitRedir(goToWhenSubmitted);
});
*/

// Use this function to add a dynamic URL for the OnSubmit-redirect. This function is automatically executed before save item.
function PreSaveAction(){
// Pass a dynamic redirect URL to the function by setting it here,
// for example based on certain selections made in the form fields like this:

    var dynamicRedirect = '/surveys/Pages/ThankYou.aspx';

    // Call the function and set the redirect URL in the form-action attribute
    setOnSubmitRedir(dynamicRedirect);
    alert(dynamicRedirect);
    // This function must return true for the save item to happen
    return true;
}

function init_fields(){
  var res = {};
  $("td.ms-formbody").each(function(){
      if($(this).html().indexOf('FieldInternalName="')<0) return;
      var start = $(this).html().indexOf('FieldInternalName="')+19;
      var stopp = $(this).html().indexOf('FieldType="')-7;
      var nm = $(this).html().substring(start,stopp);
      res[nm] = this.parentNode;
  });
  return res;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you set `window.location.href = 'SomeUrl'` at any point, it should redirect right then. Looking at your code, I dont see that anywhere.

At what point are you trying to redirect?

Comment: I thought this line is doing the redirection.  $("#aspnetForm").attr('action',newAction);

Comment: @Mary Rivers, no window.location is the standard way to do it.

Comment: Correct. With your version of jQuery, it's simply changing the form action that it will post to when the form is submitted. No action is actually being performed.

Comment: even in SharePoint 2010. $("#aspnetForm").attr('action', newAction);
In SP2007 it worked fine, in SP2010 I get the following error in the SharePoint log: System.Web.HttpException: Failed to load viewstate. can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: I added this but it still does not redirect. window.location.href = redirURL;